# For a fixed-fixed cross currency swap, can I use a curve with two floating legs to discount the cash flows?

Tags: fixed-income, swaps

I'm doing a USD to INR fixed-to-fixed cross currency swap. The default curve has a fixed and a floating rate. However, the curve that I'm looking to use has floating rates on both legs. Would this curve be appropriate to use?

Answer (score 3):

A pricing curve does not have legs.

A curve is a series of datapoints that defines either a discount factor (under some assumed model, e.g. USD cash collateral) for each business date, or a forecast interest rate (of some index e.g. 1M USD Libor).

Here is a curve: 
`GBP 3M Libor Forecast Rates: .. 13/Aug/19: 1.250%, 14/Aug/19: 1.252%, ..etc` 
Here is another curve: 
`GBP cashflows discounted under EUR Cash only CSA: .. 13/8/19: 0.99181, 14/Aug/19: 0.99112 ..etc`

To NPV your fixed-fixed cross-currency swap you need to have the `USD cashflows under a USD cash only CSA discount factor` curve and the `INR cashflows under a USD cash only CSA discount factor` curve and, to equate the values in USD, the USDINR spot FX rate.

How you generate these curves is model dependent. Always, the `USD cashflows under a USD cash only CSA discount factor` curve is calculated by analysing USD Interest rate swaps (IRSs). To get the `INR cashflows under a USD cash only CSA discount factor` curve you would typically need the local `INR IBOR forecast` curve and `INR discount curve`, calculated from local INR IRSs or otherwise and then adjust the `INR discount curve` to suit the mid-market cross-currency swap prices.

It would not necessarily matter whether the cross-currency swap prices were float-float or fixed-fixed or fixed-float, so long as you are able to make correct adjustments to accomadate those correct market prices. Most curve models are constructed with float-float  cross-currency swaps since they are most liquid in most markets.